# Cannot find symbol on findViewById(R.id.myListView)

Tags: java, android

I'm just starting to learn how to use Android Studio and I ran into this problem in trying to make a list and an array. At The line

```
myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
```

I get the error:

```
C:\Users\aweso\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAppListTest\app\src\main\java
\com\example\myapplisttest\MainActivity.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
                                             ^
```

symbol:   variable myListView

Here is the full code for my MainActivity.java file
I'm not really sure why it doesn't understand R.id.myListView

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.myapplisttest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myListView;
    String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        items = res.getStringArray(R.array.items);

        myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_listview_detail, items));


    }
}
```

Here is my xml design file

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: Show your xml design file also .

Comment: Ive added my design file to my original file. Ty for the input

Comment: you have to assign id of `ListView` as myListView . Like:android:id="@+id/myListView"

Comment: Does ```android:id="@+id/myListView"``` go into my MainActivity.java file underneath ```String[] items``` or in my xml design file?

Comment: You have to add id of your listview inside xml file .

Comment: <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"/> add id also .

Comment: Heck yes! That got rid of the error! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your Layout XML add the id:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set view id in xml layout.without id we have not access any view in activity class from xml

> id attribute to any View component in the layout file when you want to
>   reference the associated component.  That is, you want to reference
>   the component in your Java code or when defining layout in XML.

Like this:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
```